# CORS error when deployed, but works locally - Cogntio/SAM

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, cors, amazon-cognito, aws-sam

I can't figure out why I'm unable to login to my app after I `sam deploy` it. I keep getting CORS missing Allow Origin

[image]

If I run it locally with `sam local start-api` then I get a status 200 so it appears to work locally. I'm setting the CORS to `*` for the lambda function so I'm not really sure what I need to update. I have a register function that has the same response headers setup

```
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":
            },
```

but the register function doesn't have the CORS issue so that makes me think template.yaml is fine. I'm not really sure what else needs to be done. I appreciate any help with this!

login.js

```
'use strict';
//global.fetch = require('node-fetch')
require('dotenv').config();
const Cognito = require('./confirm/cognito/index');
const { verify } = require('./confirm/cognito/index');


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const json = JSON.parse(event.body)
    // console.log("EVENT BODY", event.body)

    const verificationResponse = await Cognito.signIn(json.email, json.password);
    console.log(verificationResponse)

    if (verificationResponse.statusCode !== 200) {

        console.log("Verification Error:", verificationResponse.response.message);
        const response = {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify('failed to verify user'),
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
            },
        };
        return response;
    }


    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(statusCode),
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS 
        },
    };
    return response;
};
```

Cognito.signIn function

```
function signIn(email, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    AwsConfig.getCognitoUser(email).authenticateUser(AwsConfig.getAuthDetails(email, password), {
      onSuccess: (result) => {
        console.log("RESULT", result)
        const token = {
          accessToken: result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(),
          idToken: result.getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
          refreshToken: result.getRefreshToken().getToken(),
        }
        return resolve({ statusCode: 200, response: AwsConfig.decodeJWTToken(token) });
      },

      onFailure: (err) => {
        console.log("ERROR HERE", err)
        return resolve({ statusCode: 400, response: err.message || JSON.stringify(err) });
      },
    });
  });
}
```

template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: REST API using SAM

Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs12.x
    Environment:
      Variables:
        TABLE_NAME: !Ref Table
    MemorySize: 128
    Timeout: 5
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'"
      AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
      AllowCredentials: "'*'"

Resources:
  Table:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::SimpleTable
    Properties:
      PrimaryKey:
        Name: userid
        Type: String
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1

   RegisterUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: register.handler
      Events:
        Register:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /register
            Method: post

  LoginUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: login.handler
      Events:
        Login:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /login
            Method: post
```

Comment: If you place all your servers behind a common domain you won't run into CORS issues and you do not need to use an insecure header configuration like you one you are using.

Comment: I'll probably update the origin header to be for just the domain it's meant for later, but I'd like to get this working when I run the frontend app locally for now while in development. Can you provide any advice on how to not get this error? I have it working locally for register so I just don't understand why login is having the issue.

Comment: Use a reverse proxy to place all your servers behind the same origin/domain and you don't need the headers at all.

Comment: Since it looks like you are using AWS https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/serving-content-using-fully-managed-reverse-proxy-architecture/

Answer (score 0):

headers: {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
}

Missing in HTTP call while login. Give the **headers** wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cors npm module:
Here is the link:https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
 console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: I'm not using express in my solution so I'm not so sure the cors module is applicable.